# Android use 2 listview linked together

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm pretty new on android, i'm currently reading a lot of documentation to understand how to start. I've tried to search before asking here but i'm not able to find relevant information.

My problem is have 2 listview in the same acivity.

The **Listview A** with a list of category.

The **Listview B** with a details data (at startup the values showed are based on the category 1 of the listviewA)

When a click on a item of the listviewA the data of the listViewB change to reflect the new selection and show the new list of details data.

Can someone give me the right direction or a link to a tutorial that cover this topic ?
Sorry i'm not able to post any code at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that the type of layout you are trying to make is user friendly. It would give the users far more richer UI experience if you change with an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). You can check out a tutorial [here](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html). Using this would give you the chances of engaging the user via an interaction.

[image]

Anyway, if you are sure to go with ListView then simply create a root `LinearLayout` and within this you take two `ListView`s. But taking the second one as a listview does not make sense. Rather, instead of making the second control a `ListView`, take a `TextView` to show the details.Provide the height of both layouts (`ListView` and `TextView`) according to your requirement.

Look at this **[tutorial](http://www.nurne.com/2011/06/android-how-to-multiple-listviews-in_9533.html)**

2 Listviews:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:visibility="visible">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:visibility="visible">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

1 ListView 1 TextView:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:visibility="visible">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView1" android:text="details"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

Please explain your problem a bit more. Because, in your scenario the data between the list views is connected with each other. Say, if **ListView A** is about Products so **ListView B** is about ProductDetails. So you need to declare a class variable say `ProductID` which is common entity between both data and set this variable `setOnClickListener` in ``getView()` of **ListView A** and fetch the data regarding this just after that and set the Adapter of **ListView B** with the results of this query (which may be to SQL db or RESTful server).

Comment: Thank you @Nezam, your post is very useful about how to solve the layout problem. I need for the app design these 2 list view, i can not use the ExpandableListView. But how can manage the change of data on **Listview B** when click a row in **Listview A** ? i think that i need to setup a setOnClickListener in the getView(), but how to retrieve the row clicked from the **Listview A** and requery the adapter for show the new data on the **Listview B** ? with notifyDataSetChanged() ? Thanks

Comment: Nezam, your updated it's exactly my scenario. I'm currently understand how to use sqlite into android app for update /requery the adapter **Listview B** based on item id clicked on the **Listview A**. Thanks

Comment: So have you been successful?

Comment: i'm currently study how to add sqlite support to my app and join all the works together.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this strategy before and it worked out well for me. 
Use a linear layout to position the two list views, Populate the 'category' listview and set a list adaptor for it. On this listview I set an OnItemSelectedListener  which when activated set ups the list-adaptor on the second 'detail' view.

Depending on your exact need you can either replace the detail listview's adapter or just change the content the adapter looks at and tell it to refresh.

Comment: Thank you @Elemental. i need to setup the convertView.OnItemClickListener(this) on getView()? but how to feel it to refresh? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

After get listview by id (list_A) set click listener

```
list_A.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
              //here you can get click position from parameter position
             // and do somthing in Adapter_B and then call notifyDataSetChanged() for Adapter_B
              Adapter_B.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank @AwadKab for your help. Thank to all guys of the previous post. Now it's clear how to works with it.